# Data being Stored in wrong Object

Tags: python

**SORRY FOR THE MESSY AND INEFFICIENT CODE**

Let me start with the basic rules for the code. A bag is stored under a mattress and each bag can only contain coins. Individually they can only contain a single type of coin. So the pennies bag cannot contain dimes or any other coin, only pennies.

Ok so, the Issue I have here is that when I deposit money it doesn't matter what "Bag" I deposit into, the coins automatically go to the Dime bag and I can't find where in the code this is happening. From my viewpoint, the code makes sense(Which it would to me but not the computer). I really think I just need a second set of eyes looking at it. I'm also not a python programmer which doesn't really help

```
import os
class Bags:
    def __init__(self, nOC, n, v):
        self.name = n
        self.numOfCoins = nOC
        self.value = v
        self.SetBal()

    # Setters
    def SetBal(self):
        self.amount = self.numOfCoins * self.value

    def SetCoin(self, coin):
        self.numOfCoins += coin
        self.SetBal()

    # Getters
    def GetBal(self):
        return self.amount

class Mattress:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pBag = Bags(0, "Pennies", 0.01)
        self.dBag = Bags(0, "Dimes", 0.05)
        self.nBag = Bags(0, "Nickles", 0.10)
        self.qBag = Bags(0, "Quarters", 0.25)
        self.boBag = Bags(0, "Bug-Out-Bag", 0.00)


    # Setters


    # Getters
    def GetBalances(self):
        pen = self.pBag.GetBal()
        print("Balance of pennies : $%.2f. %d pennies" % (pen,     self.pBag.numOfCoins))
        print("Balance of dimes   : $%.2f. %d dimes" % (self.dBag.GetBal(), self.dBag.numOfCoins))
        print("Balance of nickles : $%.2f" % self.nBag.GetBal())
        print("Balance of quarters: $%.2f" % self.qBag.GetBal())
        total = self.pBag.GetBal() + self.qBag.GetBal() + self.dBag.GetBal() + self.nBag.GetBal()
        print("Total              : $%.2f" % total)


def main ():
    # Check laod or what not for what you have to do and all that good stuff
    userMain = Mattress()
    mainLoop = True
    menu = '''What would you like to do?
    D. Deposit Money
    W. Withdraw Money
    T. Transfer Funds
    S. Show Balances
    E. Exit'''

    diffBags = '''
    P. Pennies
    D. Dimes
    N. Nickles
    Q. Quarters
    C. Cancel'''

    while(mainLoop):
        print(menu)

        action = input("Select an option: ")

        if action == 'D' or action == 'd' :
            depositMenu = "What bag would you like to deposit into? " + diffBags
            depLoop = True
            while(depLoop):
                print(depositMenu)

                depAction = input("Select an option: ")
                depAmt = "How much would you like to deposit? "
                if depAction == 'P' or action == 'p':
                    while True:
                        try:
                            depCoin = int(input(depAmt))
                            if depCoin < 1:
                                print("Invalid. Please enter a positive number")
                                continue
                            break
                        except ValueError:
                            print("Invalid. Please enter a positive number")

                    userMain.pBag.SetCoin(depCoin)
                    depLoop = False
                elif depAction == 'D' or action == 'd':
                    while True:
                        try:
                            depCoin = int(input(depAmt))
                            if depCoin < 1:
                                print("Invalid. Please enter a positive number")
                                continue
                            break
                        except ValueError:
                            print("Invalid. Please enter a positive number")

                    userMain.dBag.SetCoin(depCoin)
                    depLoop = False
                elif depAction == 'N' or action == 'n':
                    while True:
                        try:
                            depCoin = int(input(depAmt))
                            if depCoin < 1:
                                print("Invalid. Please enter a positive number")
                                continue
                            break
                        except ValueError:
                            print("Invalid. Please enter a positive number")

                    userMain.nBag.SetCoin(depCoin)
                    depLoop = False
                elif depAction == 'Q' or action == 'q':
                    while True:
                        try:
                            depCoin = int(input(depAmt))
                            if depCoin < 1:
                                print("Invalid. Please enter a positive number")
                                continue
                            break
                        except ValueError:
                            print("Invalid. Please enter a positive number")

                    userMain.qBag.SetCoin(depCoin)
                    depLoop = False
                elif depAction == 'C' or action == 'c':
                    depLoop = False

        elif action == 'W' or action == 'w':
            print ("working on it")


        elif action == 'T' or action == 't':
            print ("working on it")


        elif action == 'S' or action == action == 's':
            userMain.GetBalances()

        elif action == 'E' or action == 'e':
            print("Have a great day")
            mainLoop = False
        else:
            print ("Incorrect value")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your problem.

Let me explain to you how I found your problem, so next time you can find it.

I added a line to your code

```
print("Q")
userMain.qBag.SetCoin(depCoin)
```

Given what your program was trying to do I expected that to be printed when I tried to add quarters. But it was never printed, indicating that something had gone before that point.

Next I added another line:

```
depAction = input("Select an option: ")
print("GOT", depAction)
```

Then I ran the program again, and it printed.

Now I know the problem is somewhere between the two print statements. Given that the program ends up adding it to the dimes, it makes it look like somehow we ended up running the dimes-adding code even though I had entered q. I look at the code which checked for entry into the dimes section and saw the problem.

I see the problem, but the for sake of a didactic exercise I think you should find it yourself.

Comment: See also [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: So, I followed how you found it and after a few more minutes of tinkering, I was able to see what was happening. Thank you for the advice